# find the minimum possible sum by using all the numbers in an array

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I'm finding minimum possible sum from an array. e.g. array if `{1,2,3,4}`. Now I want to find the minimum possible sum from the above array like `(1 + 2)=3`, `(3+3)=6`, `(4+6)=10`. This lead to `3+6+10=19`. What would be the optimal solution?

Comment: In what language? What context? And please show some effort, what have you tried? Have you been searching the internet?

Comment: I don't understand where 19 comes from. The sum of that array is 10. The minimum possible sum of any array is its smallest element. Using all the numbers means you have to add them all anyways

Comment: @cricket_007 `1+2 = 3`, new list = `{3, 3, 4}`. sum of `3+3=6`, new list = `{4,6}`, etc. each partial sum is added to the total

Comment: @KevinL I see the progression, but what is the algorithm generating the sublists? Pick two minimal  elements at a time and sum with the remainder of the original list?

Comment: sum of two subelements gets added to the original list it seems? would make sense in a compression (huffman encoding style) context

Comment: Whatever algorithm this is, it is not finding "the sum of an array". The problem needs to be more clearly defined to be answerable.

Comment: Too bad the user `huk` can't join the conversation.

Comment: The title says "minimum" but the example appears to be looking for the maximum. Which is it?

Comment: I was looking for this problem and landed here. I'll try to explain it: you have a list of number and you have to sum them all, but you only can do it 2 each time. Then you will store the result of all sums and the sum of the sums is the result. Like what was used in the description you have [1, 2, 3, 4]. If we sum 1 + 2 = 3, the stored value is 3. Then our list has [3, 3, 4]. If we do 3 + 4 = 7 our list has [3, 7]. Last we do 3 + 7 = 10. As we had to store all the results we have 3, 7 and 10 for each sum and them sum of all those results is 20. But the best result is 19

Answer (score 7):

1. sort list low-> high
2. sum 2 lowest values (`low1+low2 = pair`), add that to the total
3. resort list with `low1` and `low2` removed, `pair` included
4. repeat 2-3 until 1 value remains, add that to total
5. total is minimized

proof is same as huffman encoding proof of optimal encoding

Comment: Didn't get your answer. what's 1 value? should i remove the low1 and low2?

Comment: until 1 value remaining, low1 and low2 should be removed from your array .

Comment: @KevinL Actually, as you can see in my answer, low1 could be replaced by the sum of low1 and low2

Comment: Your missing the step to remove `low1` and `low2`.

Comment: You can use a heap instead of resorting to turn this from O(n^2 log n) to O(n log n).  And well done on extracting a sensible interpretation from the OP's question!

Answer (score 0):

Find the minimum and remove it, then find the next minimum after the first is removed and add the two together.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript:

```js
let x = [1, 2, 2, 2, 3];
let y = [];

// check if we have more then 2 values left in the array
while(x[1] != undefined)
  // sort to make sure we get lowest values combined
  // add lowest two values, remove the second
  // push result in new array
  x.sort() && y.push(x[0] = x[0] + x.splice(1, 1)[0]);

// add all results
let result = y.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);

console.log(result);
```

You can create a function that does this for every array you pass into it. Very cool if you are into functional programming:

```js
const array = [1, 2, 2, 2, 3];

const add = (x, y = []) => (
    (x, y) => x.sort() && 
      y.push(x[0] = x[0] + x.splice(1, 1)[0]) && 
      x[1] ? 
      add(x, y) : 
    y.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0))(x.slice(), y);

console.log(add(array));

// the original array is unmodified
console.log(array);
```

Comment: I am almost certain that this gives a non-optimal value because you don't resort the array to ensure you always sum the lowest two values. Your algorithm gives 25 for [1,2,2,2,3] but the optimal sum is 23

Comment: @KevinL You are right. I didn't realise that was the requirement. Updated.